# How is this relay circuit Working

Tags: relay

I have this relay circuit to cut the ignition power of a vechile. Can someone please explain how this immobiliser                 circuit is working.

[image]

Comment: What's an MVT600?  What's the make and model of the relay?

Comment: MVT600 is a vehicle tracking device. I dont have info about the relay.

Comment: Did you miss your payment? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The MVT600, whatever it is, it should have the ground connection, without which it can't possibly control the relay solenoid.

Having said this, the function of this immobilizer is easy to explain. MVT600 normally keep the relay switched on thru pin 85 and 86 by pulling the yellow wire to the ground. This in turn closes the relay contacts (pin 30 and 87a) so that ignition key is enabled.

When the immobilizer is active, the yellow wire is left floating and relay is killed thus cutting off the 12V to the ignition key.

Comment: I am designing a device like MVT600. This relay circuit is external to the device. I need to control this relay from vehicle battery voltage to cut the ignition when required. In my opinion, All I can do on the board is , connect the red line with drain of a FET. (Vds> Battery Voltage) & control the gate of the FET from GPIO.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly MVT600 sends a high signal, let's say, a determined voltage which is going to energize the relay coil and hence turning off the ignition. As I do not know about relay's specs and MVT datasheet itself, I am only capable of assume the most likely answer(in my humble opinion)